# PyDev is trying to import non-test-related files?

Tags: pydev

When I try to auto-discover and run my tests in PyDev I get many import errors...

For example:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.4.0.2012020116\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 307, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
ImportError: No module named docs.conf
ERROR: Module: docs.conf could not be imported (file: C:/Users/User/Documents/workspaces/workspace1/test/docs/conf.py).
done.
```

As you can see the "conf.py" file is just a file that is needed for documentation: not actual code.  How do I limit PyDev from being over-zealeous when searching for tests?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently possible only in the latest PyDev nightly build.

Go to: window > preferences > pydev > pyunit and add a parameter: --include_files=test*.py

This will be actually released on PyDev 2.6.0.

To grab the nightly build, see: http://pydev.org/download.html